# How invert the result used the method sort

Tags: python

I need a feedback, I don't know how to invert the result. I mean  for example if I have a 289 that the result is a 982.

```
def numeros4s():
    numero_n = int(input("ingresar un numero porfavor: "))
    listax = []
    listax.append(numero_n **2) #recordar siempre poner formulas dentro del parentesis
    print "la raiz cuadrada de: ",numero_n," es: ",listax

numeros4s()
```

Comment: What does the code have to do with the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
number = 123
int("".join(reversed(str(number))))
# 321
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> num = 289
>>> reversed_num = int(str(num)[::-1])
>>> reversed_num
982
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to reverse a number, that would be this:

```
n = 289
n_str = str(n)
print(''.join(reversed(n_str)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
def reverse(num):
    result = 0
    while num > 0:
        result = result * 10 + num % 10
        num /= 10
    return result

print(reverse(18539)) # --> 93581
```